# javascript - global variable being persisted in forEach loop. scope issue?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, ecmascript-6, scope

I'm having an issue looping through an array of objects (twice) and modifying a nested object.

I have an array of roles that contain permissions assigned to that role. I also have an array of all possible permissions that can be assigned to a role.

On my html page, I need to list each role... and within each role I need to list **all** the permissions as checkboxes. The permission checkbox needs to be checked if the permission has already been assigned to that role. To do that, I need to:

1. Loop through all roles
2. For each role, copy the ID's of all the attached permissions to an array.
3. Replace the role's permissions with the list of all permissions.
4. Loop through the role's new permissions array.
5. For each permission, add a new "selected" property, whos value is true or false depending on if the permission's ID is in the array of ID's set in #2

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amcardwell/Lamse2z4/123/). Here is the operation:

```
roles.forEach(function(role){

    // Get list of all the permission ids before the permissions are replaced with the list of all permissions
    var permission_ids = role.permissions.map(p => { return p.id });

    // Replace the roles permissions with the global list of permissions
    role.permissions = permissions;

    role.permissions.forEach(function(permission){
        permission.selected = permission_ids.indexOf(permission.id) > -1;
    });
});
```

The problem is, the permissions variable is binding to the local role.permissions array and is being persisted across every iteration of role.

The result of the operation *should* be a list of roles containing a list of **all** permissions, and in each permission there is a "selected" property based on if the permission is attached to the role.

Rather, in the end... the permissions of each role is the result of the operation of the last iteration of the role loop.

I can accept an alternative solution, but I would also like an explanation of why this is happening?

Comment: Thanks, but how do I create a localized copy of the permissions variable inside the loop, then let role.permissions reference the copy?

Comment: `role.permissions = permissions.slice().map(p => Object.assign({}, p));` - or `role.permissions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(permissions));`

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX. I changed role.permissions to `role.perissions = permissions.slice().map(p => Object.assign({}, p));` and it worked correctly. [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ksrmpue5/1/)

Comment: @JaromandaX Your answer fixed my problem but I dont know if it should be marked correct. At least I dont seem to have the ability to make it correct for some reason...

Comment: it's a comment, so no you can't mark it correct :p

Comment: To be honest, the code in your fiddle has so much I don't understand (the logic if it, I do understand the code itself) that making a copy of `permissions` seems to be only  one *problem* fixed as far as I can see

Comment: Users have roles, and roles have permissions. In my CMS, I have a page that allows the admin to modify the permissions for each role. Each role has a series of checkboxes underneath it (each representing the permission’s respective role) that is checked/unchecked based on the “selected” property. The thing is, I need to list all the permissions under each role, to allow the user to see all available permissions... not just the selected ones.

Answer (score 0):

The loop is running correctly but `role.permissions` is being reset each loop. Presumably you are only using that value after the loop has finished  and, seeing as the variable can only hold one value, it is always the last value.
Simplest solution is to decide what you want to do with role.permissions and permission.selected and do that inside the loop (say creating the html for each role and outputting to the page)

Answer (score 0):

You might use something like this to keep the `permissions` array safe.
But your choice of data structures looks strange to me.

```js
var roles = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Viewer",
    "permissions": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "View all Posts"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "View a Single Post"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Editor",
    "permissions": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "View all Posts"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "View a Single Post"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Add a Post"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Edit a Post"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Moderator",
    "permissions": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "View all Posts"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "View a Single Post"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Edit a Post"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Delete a Post"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Flag a Post"
      }
    ]
  }
];

var permissions = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "View all Posts"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "View a single Post"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Add a Post"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Edit a Post"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Delete a Post"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Flag a Post"
  }
];

roles.forEach(function(role) {

  console.log("On role: " + role.name);

  permissions.forEach(function(permission) {
    var role_permission = role.permissions.filter(e => e.id === permission.id)[0];
    if (!role_permission)
      role.permissions.splice(permission.id - 1, 0, Object.assign({selected: false}, permission));
    else role_permission.selected = true;
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(permissions))
  console.log(JSON.stringify(role.permissions));
});
```